# Guidance with header and main template - seek best practice please

Tags: c++, coding-style

I'm new to C++ and was needing some help in terms of using the best coding practices. Basically I have created my header file (character.h) with the following data:

```
using namespace std;

class character
{
    //available to all
    public:
        character();
        ~character(){};

        int getHP(){return hp;};
        int damage(int _damage);
        int levelUp(int _xp);

        void setHP(int _hp){hp = _hp;};
        string getName(){return name;};

    protected:
        int hp;
        string name;
};

class player:public character
{
    public:
        player();
        ~player(){};
    protected:
        string name;
        int lvl;
        int xp;
};

class enemy:public character
{
    public:
        enemy(string _name, int _hp);
        ~enemy(){};
    protected:
        string name;
        int lvl;
        int xp;
};
```

I was trying to generate the main file (main.cpp) from this data

```
#include "character.h"
player::player()
{
    cout << "\t\t\nPlease enter your name: \n\t\t";
    cin >> name;
};

int main()
{
    //some code
    return 0;
}
```

But I keep getting errors

```
"undefined reference to `character::character()"
```

Can someone please help me, why am I getting this error and also is this approach the best practice for the layout of this design?

Comment: Please don't do a `using namespace` in a header file!  Not even in toy projects -- just don't get in to the habit.

Comment: Thank you for the comment John I will keep that in mind for the future, thanks

Comment: Why are level and experience not members of the base class?

Comment: Don't put a semi-colon at the end of a function definition: `player::player() { ... };` because it leaves an empty declaration (between the close brace and the semi-colon) which can generate warnings.

Comment: @Perl_noob: You don't need semi-colon after the function definitions like `int getHP(){return hp;};`. `int getHP(){return hp;}` will do just fine. You need some mana with hp though :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the constructor(s) for character in your code file:

```
character::character():
  hp(10),
  name("default")
{
}
character::character (std::string name): hp(10) [...]
character::character (int hp): name("Default") [...]
character::character (std::string name, int hp) [...]
```

This makes sure that all your instance variables are defined.

Since you define a destructor, you must obey the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) and define a copy constructor and assignment operator as well.

On a side note, you should use a convention to name your class/instance variables: `myName`, `_name`, or `name_` are quiet common.  Using [cppcheck](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppcheck/) may save you some time/hassle as well.

Comment: in my "character.h" or my "main.cpp"?

Comment: also why do I need to define it if it has a null constructor'()' - I thought creating "character()" took no args?

Comment: Unless you are using header only libraries, I would keep all the code in code files and all documentation and definitions in header files. Your character constructor could take any number of arguments -- that is your call.  However, if you define any constructors, the compiler will not give you one for free.

Comment: The example is in the code above.  Just copy the first five lines of the code into your main.cpp file and you should be fine -- at least for the character class.  You could put all your classes under a namespace as well, it's good practice.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create the **definition** for your default constructors `character::character()` and `player::player()`. While default constructors take no arguments, you still need need to provide a definition for them. If they do absolutely nothing, not even member initialization, then you could simply do what you did for your destructors: `character() { }` and `player() { }`.

However, you could (and you probably should), initialize the data members in the constructors, using initializer list syntax. For example, for the character class, it would be:

```
character() : hp(100), name("Mario") { }
```

Note that you don't need the semicolon after `}`. Or you could **NOT** use initializer lists and have:

```
character() {
    hp = 100;
    name = "Mario";
}
```